# Socket Exception error

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception

I have a networking socket program in C#.net.
I have to connect with an ip: 169.254.74.65 and port:7998 and my ip is:169.254.74.63.
So I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class MyTcpListener{
   public static void Main(){
       TcpListener server = null;
         try{
             Int32 port = 7998;
             IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("169.254.74.65");
             server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
             server.Start();
             Byte[] bytes = new Byte[500];
             String data = null;
             while (true){
             Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
             TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
             data = null;
             NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
             int i;
             while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0){
             data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
             Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
             }
             client.Close();}
          }
        catch (SocketException e){
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);}
        finally{ server.Stop();  }
```

Ping works fine between two IPs. Even telnet 169.254.74.65 7998 gives me proper result and listens to the correct messages. So the connection is solid. 
But when I run the above code it shows an exception:

```
> SocketException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
   at MyTcpListener.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\TCPListener\TCPListener\Program.cs:line 12
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: have you tried 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of the 169.254.xx.xx address. Check: Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)

Comment: yes I have tried 127.0.0.1 and port 7998 but it doestnot work. it just waits for the connection infinitely.

Comment: Dont tell me - that you haven't hit it with a client?

Comment: Didn't get your point. The client meant some other machine or some tcpClient program?? I have tried it with some tcpClient program and it works fine. but when dealing with another machine with IP 169.254.74.65 and port 7998, it gives the socket error.

Comment: Where did you get that IP from? I believe that is your public IP - which is representational purpose only - you cannot open a socket using the Dynamically assigned IP. You always open the IP on Localhost and do router config etc. to route everything to your machine.

Comment: my ethernet ip is 169.254.74.63. That machine has an ip: 169.254.74.65 as set by the handler of the machine. I did not assign any ip to my machine. When my machine is connected to this Nihon Kohden machine with an ethernet cable and i use TCPListener to listen to it, do i use the ip of that machine or mine? (I want to clear this out first).

Comment: plus the ping and telnet work exactly fine with the ip: 169.254.74.65. then whats the issue with listening to that ip:port connection?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me:

Have you actually hit your server at 127.0.0.1:7998 from a client socket code?

[image]

**Update**
So your Server IP is 169.xx.xx.65, while your own DEV machine IP is 169.xx.xx.63
Your code is something which creates a TCP Server connection. While (if I am not wrong) - you only need to connect to that HL7 machine.

Understand that the HL7 machine will be the server and your machine will be the client. So you just need TcpClient. Something like:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("169.xx.xx.65", 7998);
```

Use Connect/GetStream etc methods per: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yeah it works that way. But the machine am dealing with is a Nihon Kohden HL7 system which has an IP: 169.254.74.65 and connects to the port 7998 (Set inside the machine). Now tell me whats wrong in here?

Comment: So this C# code is deployed on the machine with IP being 169.XXX.XX.XX - is that your LAN (intranet) ip range?

Comment: Oh it was all my fault and the most stupid and foolish one! I was creating a tcp server instead of tcp client. a tcp server cannot listen to another server. LOL. Now i made a tcp client so all is good.